# Subquery in DECLARE statement brings back more than one value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, declare

I have the stored procedure below that I need help on.  Its purpose is to find differences between a staging DB and the production DB.  When it finds the difference, the stored procedure will update the production DB with the correct information.  The problem is that sometimes there is more than one difference between the DBs.  The stored procedure can only handle one difference between the DBs at a time.  I want the stored procedure to be able to handle as many differences as it finds.  If it can only handle one difference at a time, the stored procedure would need to be running continually.  Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

```
            `BEGIN TRANSACTION

            DECLARE @FILENUM NVARCHAR(30)

            SET @FILENUM = ( SELECT TOP 1 B.ID FROM DBO.ABC_FILE_NUMBER F WITH ( NOLOCK )

                            JOIN DBO.REL_PRIMARY_NUMBER R WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON F.ID = R.FILE_NUMBER_ID

                            JOIN DBO.ABC_PRIMARY_NUMBER P WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON R.PRIMARY_NUMBER_ID = P.ID

                            JOIN DBO.STAGINGDATA S WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON F.FILE_NUMBER_ALIAS = S.ID

                            WHERE S.PRIMARYNUMBER <> P.PRIMARY_NUMBER_ALIAS)

            DECLARE @PRIMNUM NVARCHAR(30)

            SET @PRIMNUM = ( SELECT DISTINCT P.ID FROM DBO.STAGINGDATA S WITH ( NOLOCK )

                            JOIN DBO.ABC_PRIMARY_NUMBER P WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON P.PRIMARY_NUMBER_ALIAS = S.PRIMARYNUMBER

                            WHERE S.ID = ( SELECT F.FILE_NUMBER_ALIAS FROM ABC_FILE_NUMBER WHERE ID = @FILENUM))

            UPDATE  DBO.REL_PRIMARY_NUMBER
            SET     PRIMARY_NUMBER_ID = @PRIMNUM
            WHERE   FILE_NUMBER_ID = @FILENUM

            UPDATE  DBO.ABC_WORKSPACE
            SET     PRIMARY_NUMBER_ID = @PRIMNUM
            WHERE   FILE_NUMBER_ID = @FILENUM

            UPDATE  DBO.ABC_DOCUMENT
            SET     PRIMARY_NUMBER_ID = @PRIMNUM
            WHERE   FILE_NUMBER_ID  = @FILENUM

            UPDATE  DBO.ABC_FILE_NUMBER
            SET     MODIFIED_TIME = GETDATE(), MODIFIED_BY_ID = '21403'
            WHERE   FILE_NUMBER_ID = @FILENUM

            COMMIT`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a loop as below to "walk" through each `@FILENUM` and do the work using the same scripts you are using now.  A better option would be to rewrite each DML operation to perform the work in a set based way and act on all the rows at once, but that might not be an option for you depending on what other actions you are performing.

Here's a simple setup to loop through each FileNum:

```
declare @Process table (ProcessId int identity(1,1), FileNum nvarchar(30));

-- stage *all* the fileNums (perhaps in some order?)
insert into @Process (FileNum)
    SELECT B.ID FROM DBO.ABC_FILE_NUMBER F WITH ( NOLOCK )
    JOIN DBO.REL_PRIMARY_NUMBER R WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON F.ID = R.FILE_NUMBER_I
    JOIN DBO.ABC_PRIMARY_NUMBER P WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON R.PRIMARY_NUMBER_ID = P.ID
    JOIN DBO.STAGINGDATA S WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON F.FILE_NUMBER_ALIAS = S.ID
    WHERE S.PRIMARYNUMBER <> P.PRIMARY_NUMBER_ALIAS


declare @ProcessId int,
        @FileNum nvarchar(30);

select @ProcessId = min(ProcessId) from @Process;

while @ProcessId is not null
begin

    select @FileNum = FileNum from @Process where ProcessId = @ProcessId;

    print 'Working on FileNum: ' + @FileNum;
    /*
        do your work here
    */

    select @ProcessId = min(ProcessId) from @Process where ProcessId > @ProcessId;

end
```

The set based operation would look something like:

```
declare @Stage table (FileNum nvarchar(30), PrimNum nvarchar(30) primary key  (FileNum));

-- stage the (FileNum:PrimNum) dataset
insert into @Stage (FileNum)
    select FileNum, PrimNum from dbo.yourTables where yourColumn ...

--now perform set based updates
UPDATE  rpn
SET     PRIMARY_NUMBER_ID = s.PRIMNUM
from    @Stage s 
join    DBO.REL_PRIMARY_NUMBER rpn on
        s.FileNum = rpn.FILE_NUMBER_ID

UPDATE  aw
SET     PRIMARY_NUMBER_ID = s.PRIMNUM
from    @Stage s
join    DBO.ABC_WORKSPACE aw on
        s.FileNum = aw.FILE_NUMBER_ID

-- and so on...
```